# How do I write a script that exits a cell that is being edited

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

If I enter a value in cell A1 without exiting the cell [image: 1]. Before I exit editing A1 I run a script that at some point selects another cell B1 [image: 2], while A1 is still being edited. When I then click C1, the value moves along to the cell B1 before C1 is selected [image: 3]. That is what I want to prevent. The value should remain in A1 when the script selects B1 and I select C1.

How do I call for the initial state of cell A1 being edited to stop before I select another cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to call a script when a cell is being edited because Google Apps Script is not able to detect that a cell is being edited.

Resources

- https://develoepers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets